# Synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` on the main thread is deprecated warning pointing to jquery.js, unable to find issue within code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a warning within the Chrome Lighthouse > Best Practices section:
Synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience...

This points to line 10079 of jquery.js (currently using uncompressed with plans to move to .min after fixing this issue)

The code at 10079 is:

```
xhr.open(
    options.type,
    options.url,
    options.async,
    options.username,
    options.password
);
```

This issue seems to be occurring only when the code to pull in the header and footer is included on the website page (currently building in html with js code below used to load header and footer on all pages)

(Code within "header-footer.js")

```
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("/header.html");
});

$(function(){
  $("#footer").load("/footer.html");
});
```

This file (header-footer.js) is then loaded into the pages as so:

```
<script src="/assets/js/header-footer.js"></script>
```

With each page including a div of:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

The header and footer load correctly, however when testing in Lighthouse with Google Chrome (latest version) the warning of Synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` on the main thread is deprecated... shows while pointing to the jquery file. Appears to be an issue with async.

After searching multiple fixes, a suggestion was to load this through the server, with the:

```
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("/header.html");
});
```

becoming:

```
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("https://domain/header.html");
});
```

The issue persists after changing to this.

I have also added true/false to the js function, as suggested in another answer from another post example:

```
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("/header.html", true);
});
```

I am looking to remove the warning on the code, while allowing the header and footer to be loaded from a separate html file.

Adding the header and footer html code into each page is not an option which would work for the website due to the size and complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your approach, loading the page necessitates (at least) four requests:

- `/page.html`
- `/assets/js/header-footer.js`
- `/header.html`
- `/footer.html`

If the last two (for header and footer) are synchronous requests (which seems to be the behavior of the jQuery [`.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function), the user cannot start interacting with the page until they have been completed. That's what Google calls a "detrimental effect".

But even if they were asynchronous: The user would not see the page in its final shape until header and footer have been loaded. Worse, they can already have started interacting with the page (aiming at a checkbox in order to click it, say) before header and footer are inserted and displace the checkbox that the user is aiming at. The user might then click the wrong checkbox. I consider moving parts of a page after they have become interactive or just visible to be even more detrimental to user experience than delayed page loading.

I think you misinterpreted the advice to "load through the server". The advice refers to having a web server implementation (for example, using [express](/questions/tagged/express) together with a [template engine](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)) that is able to assemble the entire page with header and footer *on the server* in response to *one* request (`/page.html`) only. But you don't mention any server in your question.

You can avoid the Google warning and omit the two last requests altogether if you use the jQuery [`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) function instead of `.load` and write the HTML contents directly into the Javascript source code like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#header").html(`<h1>This is my header</h1>
<p>And this is the content in the header section.
 The header section ends with a rule.</p>
<hr>`);
  $("#footer").html(`<h1>This is my footer</h1>...`);
});
```

But assembling pages on the server is the preferable solution. Template engines typically have an include statement for including things like headers and footers, see [this example](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, that has solved the issue, not that great with js currently so hadn't even thought to include the html within the js scripts for the header and footer.